# Radius of convergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis

1. Consider $\sum z^{n!}$. What will be its radius of convergence?
2. What will be the interval of convergence of  $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} x^{\log m}$ where $x>0$.

Comment: What are $l,n$ in the second problem?

Comment: Sorry! it is log I have changed it...

Answer (score 1):

1. when $0<x<1$, $x^{n!} < x^n$ hence $\sum x^{n!} <\infty$ and $R\ge 1$. When $x >1$, $x^ {n!}\nrightarrow 0$ hence $R\le 1$. $R=1$.
2. Consider the ratio test:
   $$
   x^{\log (m+1)}/x^ {\log m} = x^ {\log (m+1)-\log m}
   =x^ {\log(1+1/m)} 
   \\
   = \exp(\log(1+1/m)\log x) = \exp(\log x/m + O(m^{-2}))
   \\
   = 1 + \log x/m + O(m^{-2})
   $$
   The interval is, according to [Gauss's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html), such as
   $$
   \log x < -1 \implies x < e^{-1}
   $$
   hence the answer is $[0,1/e)$.

Detail: I used
$$\log(1+u) = u+O(u^2)
\\ \exp(u) = 1+u+O(u^2)
$$when $u\to 0$.

Comment: I am not getting these simplifications in 2. May I get some more explanations.

Comment: I removed my comment :-).